# "Maximum-Count of Selected Items"-Validator for ListBox

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, listbox

i have asked myself if there is an easy way to check if a ListBox has a maximum of 5 selected items. There must be at least one and at most 5 items selected.

Do i need a CustomValidator with server-side validation?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a CustomValidator routine.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ListBox5ItemsValidator" runat="server"
    OnServerValidate="ListBox5ItemsValidator_ServerValidate"
    ClientValidationFunction="ListBox5ItemsValidator_ClientValidate"
    ControlToValidate="MyListBox">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Server-side code:

```
protected void ListBox5ItemsValidator_ServerValidate(
        object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {

    int selectionCount = 0;
    foreach (ListItem item in MyListBox.Items) {
        if (item.Selected) selectionCount++;
    }
    args.IsValid = (selectionCount >= 1 && selectionCount <= 5);
}
```

Client-side code:

```
function ListBox5ItemsValidator_ClientValidate(sender, args) {
    var selectionCount = $('#<% =MyListBox.ClientID %> option:selected').length;
    args.IsValid = (selectionCount >= 1 && selectionCount <= 5);
};
```

Replace MyListBox with the actual name of your ListBox that you want to validate.  If your ListBox is contained inside of other container controls, you may need a little more work to reference the control both on the server and client side.  For instance, if it is contained in a FormView control called FormView1, you would use

```
ListBox MyListBox = (ListBox)FormView1.FindControl("MyListBox");
```

Comment: I have tried to implement the CustomValidator server event, but i'm getting `Message: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors. Parameter name: element`. I think it has something to do with the Ajax-ValidationCalloutExtender.

Comment: I have found something about this issue, seems to be a problem with the ValidationCalloutExtender and `EnableClientScript="false"`.
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/17713?ProjectName=ajaxcontroltoolkit

Comment: This page describes the problem better and provides a solution(even for not so trivial things like my customvalidator):
http://www.junnark.com/Articles/Article0001.aspx
If you could provide a  ClientValidationFunction with jQuery i will mark this question as answered. Thank you.